# How to use JSON Array as foreign key to the same table? (Sequelize+ Postgres)

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following table:

| id | name | brothers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | `[3, 4]` |
| 2 | Ben | `[]` |
| 3 | Mary | `[1, 4]` |
| 4 | Peter | `[1, 3]` |

How to set up a relation where I could get all brothers data in single query on  single record? the brothers column is using Postgres Array type.

Right now I am using 2 queries, 1 to get John, and then query again to get brothers info based on his brothers IDs.

I found the following in Sequelize Docs:

> Sequelize supports self-referential Many-to-Many relationships,
> intuitively:

```
Person.belongsToMany(Person, { as: 'Children', through: 'PersonChildren' })
// This will create the table PersonChildren which stores the ids of the objects.
```

But I couldn't get it work with:

```
People.belongsToMany(People, { as: 'Brothers', through: 'peopleBrothers', foreignKey: 'brothers' })
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You can not define foreign keys between a JSON column and another column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name even with Sequelize? as it been described to create a junction table automatically.

Comment: I don't know Sequelize, but it's technically not possible in the database unless you use a properly normalized data model.

Comment: If you're talking about using Sequelize for joining tables only then in this case it also cannot join columns of different types because it's not allowed by DB itself